# Best way to write repeated code in VBA Dependent List of Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have total 15 columns with Data Validation Drop-down.
Drop-down for Column 2 to 15 are dependent on value selected in Column 1.
Drop-down for Column 3 is dependent on value selected in Column 2. If Column 3 value is selected directly then value for Column 2 must be populated in the excel cell of column 2.
Drop-down for Column 5 and 6 are dependent on Column 4 and so on.

Please find the code below for Column 2 and 3 dependent on Column 1 which is very lengthy. Is there any best/dynamic way to write this code to make sure all of my requirement is satisfied in VBA?

```
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim ListBoxRow As Long
    Dim filterRowNum As Long
    Dim col2 As String
    Dim col3 As String
    rowNum = 2
    filterRowNum = 2
    col2 = ""
    col3 = ""

    Do Until Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = ""
        If InStr(1, Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 1).Value, activeCellValue, vbTextCompare) Then
            If filterRowNum = 2 Then
                col2 = col2 & Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 2).Value
                col3 = col3 & Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 5).Value
            Else
                If InStr(col2, Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 2).Value) = 0 Then
                    col2 = col2 & "," & Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 2).Value
                End If
                If InStr(col3, Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 5).Value) = 0 Then
                    col3 = col3 & "," & Worksheets("Col1Col2Col3Sheet").Cells(rowNum, 5).Value
                End If
            End If
            filterRowNum = filterRowNum + 1
        End If
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Loop
    With Worksheets("CustomSpreadsheet").Range("F" & ActiveCellRow).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=col2
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    With Worksheets("CustomSpreadsheet").Range("G" & ActiveCellRow).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=col3
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Comment: is this being called from a worksheet_change event?

Comment: Yes. Condition inside the worksheet_change event is:If Worksheets("CustomSpreadsheet").Cells(1, Target.Column) = "Col1" And Target.Cells(1).Value <> "" Then call this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way - abstract out all of the work to separate methods: one to give you a list of all unique matches, and the other to set up the validation:

```vb
'Set a cell validation list
'You might consider expanding this to also delete any previously-selected
'  value if it's not in the list of values being added
Sub SetCellList(c As Range, lst As String)
    With c.Validation
        .Delete
        If Len(lst) > 0 Then 'make sure there's something to add...
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=lst
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowError = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

'Return a comma-delimited list of all unique "sub-values"
'columnsToCheck: array of cell at the top(s) of the column(s) you want to scan for matches
'valuestoCheck: array of the value to look for in columnsToCheck
'returnColLetter: when a match is made, return all unique values from this column
Function Uniques(columnsToCheck, valuestoCheck, returnColLetter As String) As String
    Dim arrA, arrB, rngCheck As Range, r As Long, i As Long, c As Range, n As Long, rng As Range
    Dim dict As Object, bMatch As Boolean
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    'translate array of column header cells to array of 2D arrays
    'pick up values from return column
    For i = LBound(columnsToCheck) To UBound(columnsToCheck)
        Set c = columnsToCheck(i)
        If i = LBound(columnsToCheck) Then
            Set rng = c.Parent.Range(c, c.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp))
            arrB = rng.EntireRow.Columns(returnColLetter).Value 'values to return
            n = rng.Rows.Count '# of rows
        Else
            Set rng = c.Resize(n, 1) 'columns should be all the same size...
        End If
        columnsToCheck(i) = ToArray(rng)
    Next i
    'loop rowa to check and collect any matches
    For r = 1 To n
        bMatch = True
        'loop columns to check
        For i = LBound(columnsToCheck) To UBound(columnsToCheck)
            If columnsToCheck(i)(r, 1) <> valuestoCheck(i) Then
                bMatch = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If bMatch Then dict(arrB(r, 1)) = True
    Next r
    Uniques = Join(dict.keys, ",")
End Function

'Safely get a 2D array from a range, even if the range is a single cell
Function ToArray(rng As Range)
    Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    If rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        arr(1, 1) = rng.Value
        ToArray = arr
    Else
        ToArray = rng.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Example usage using a change event:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, v
    
    'this range depends only on the cell to the left
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("N2:N25"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            v = Trim(c.Value)
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                'set list in next column over
                SetCellList c.Offset(0, 1), _
                            Uniques(Array(lists.Cells(1, "A")), _
                                    Array(v), "B")
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    
    'this range depends only on the two cells to the left
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O2:O25"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            v = Trim(c.Value)
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                'set list in next column over
                SetCellList c.Offset(0, 1), _
                    Uniques(Array(lists.Cells(1, "A"), lists.Cells(1, "B")), _
                            Array(Trim(c.Offset(0, -1).Value), Trim(c.Value)), "C")
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked but how can I make a cell dependent on values present in two columns in this case?